# How does CLion show parameters' name when parameter popup in macro?

Tags: parameters, popup, clion, parameterinfo

[image]

The parameters' name will appear.

But when it is defined in a marco, it disappeared:

[image]

[image]

Is here a way to display the name of parameters in macro? or just it is a feature of CLion?